# django 1.3 list_filter presentation layer - enums

Tags: django, django-admin

I'd like to use django `list_filter` to filter by some enum value. Due to that I've got of course panel with values like `0, 1, 2,..., 1337` and so on.
I wonder If I will be able to change this values into it's text representation. For example 0 into horse, 1 into cow, 2 into Moses and so on.
Is it possible to achieve that "easily"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use [choices](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.4/ref/models/fields/#choices)

```
SOME_CHOICES = (
    (0, 'horse'),
    (1, 'cow'),
    (2, 'moses'),
    ...
)

# in model
some_field = models.PositiveIntegerField(choices=SOME_CHOICES)
```